# Struggling with subquery/JOIN

Tags: mysql

Please forgive my ignorance before I start but I'm trying to reference the same table twice in a query to bring back a single row. For whatever reason I really struggle getting my head around the sub query/join concept. To ensure I could actually get the data I satrted with this basic query:

```
SELECT aCR
, COUNT(CASE WHEN aSID = 30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS wtng
, CASE WHEN aSID = 30 THEN DATE_FORMAT(aAT, '%d %b %H:%i') ELSE NULL END AS wAT
, COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(aC, CURDATE()) <=30 AND aSID != 30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS rpt
, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(aC, CURDATE()) <=30 AND asID != 30 THEN DATE_FORMAT(aAT, '%d %b %H:%i') ELSE NULL END AS rAT

FROM a

WHERE aCR = 1111111111 AND aHID = 44 GROUP BY aID
```

which gave me this

```
        aCR     |  wtng    |      wAT     |  rpt  |      rAT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1111111111  |    0     |     NULL     |   1   |  16 Sep 12:39
    1111111111  |    1     | 17 Sep 17:59 |   0   |      NULL
```

This is the right data but I need it on a single row thus:

```
        aCR     |  wtng    |      wAT     |  rpt  |      rAT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1111111111  |    1     | 17 Sep 17:59 |   1   |  16 Sep 12:39
```

The may be times when there is no match against aCR and therefore no row returned but I need a row returning if wtng is 1, rpt is 1 or both are 1... And this is where I'm really struggling. I've tried 
many subquery combinations but just can't seem to get it so I'm looking for help... Apologies in advance if this is a really dumb question or if I'm missing the completely obvious but right now I feel as though I'm just going round in circles...

Really appreciate the down vote, whoever it was - it makes learning so much more fun

Comment: Please provide the table structure and explain, where the `aID` column is - that one is used in the group by.

Comment: @DaDaDom The table is simple  The group by was purely to split out the COUNT aggregation. I'll amend question to include structure

Comment: @Filious: please include your `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) and maybe some sample data.

Comment: @Tobia Tesan I've included the table structure which is relatively simple and the only data I have right now is whats shown above...

Answer (score 0):

@DaDaDom, @Tobia Tesan thanks for at least responding to my request for help - I got some great help from another forum and here's the answer

```
SELECT aCR
     , MAX(wtng) AS wtng
     , MAX(wAT)  AS wAT
     , MAX(rpt)  AS rpt
     , MAX(rAT)  ASrAT 
  FROM ( "my query here" ) AS yourquery
GROUP
BY aCR
```